# Is any way to get shrink URLs to the t.co domain from API?

Tags: twitter

Is any way to get shrink URLs to the t.co domain from API ?. In case of to.ly domain, we use the `http://to.ly/api.php?json=1&longurl=` from Twitter API. what is the way to get the URLs to the t.co domain from API ???

Answer (score 0):

Twitter does not provide an API for their t.co URL shortening service. It is not possible to create new t.co short URLs programmatically.

Answer (score 0):

t.co is not public -- it is Twitter's own internal shortening service.  A "hack" that you can use is to have a private Twitter account that you can tweet your url to programmatically, and from there you can retrieve the t.co url.